# In react + redux, what's the best way to access a parent's property from a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having this problem where i open a form inside a Dialog (from material-ui). The dialog has it's own state ({open: true}) and some properties that handle that state (handleOpen, handleClose, funcs that setState to either true or false). Where i get lost is when, after successfully submitting the form i want to close the parent dialog. Basically, i want to call the handleClose fn on the parent.

```
export class ContactFormDialog extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
state = {
    open: false
};
handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
};
handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
};
render() {
    let style = {
        margin: 12,
    };
    const actions = [
        <RaisedButton
            label={resources.general.cancelLabel}
            primary={false}
            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
        />
    ];
    return (
        <div>
            <RaisedButton
                onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
                label={resources.contact.askForInfo}
                primary={true}
                style={style}
            />
            <Dialog
                actions={actions}
                modal={true}
                open={this.state.open}
                autoScrollBodyContent={true}
                onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                title={resources.contact.contactUs}
                ref="contactFormDialog"
            >
                <div className="text-center">
                    <ContactForm />
                </div>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Contact form looks like this 
class ContactForm extends React.Component {

```
onSubmit = (values) => {
    // print the form values to the console
    this.props.submitRequest(values);
    //this is what i tried but fails to compile because this.refs.contactFD is a Element/ReactInstance and they do not have a 'handleClose' property/method.
    if (this.refs.contactFormDialog) {
        this.refs.contactFormDialog.handleClose();

    }

};

public render() {
    return (
        <ContactFormView onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
    );
}
```

}

What would be a good practice to handle this kind of problem? (accessing a parent property from inside the child)

Comment: Why not pass a callback to the child?

Comment: @Chris. You are right. It's the same problem and actually a very simple one to handle. Not sure why i didn't think of it, being as obvious as it is. I might have i just gotten too deep to see the plain simple answer. Thanks.